# How to fix VSCode ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Problem Statement: VScode run can't find Module

Module Structure:
**c:\my_pkg**

```
my_pkg
  my_pkg
    start.py
 tests
    test_start.py
```

test_start.py has a line: `import my_pkg.start`

Issue: Error is : `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_pkg'`

I tried to fix it by modifying the launch.json file. But no luck!

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "C:\\my_pkg",
            "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}"},
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean this structure?

[image]

It seems has no problem, it works well on my computer. Could you try this code in the `test_start.py` file, to check whether it includes the workspace folder `my_pkg`(the parent folder of my_pkg)?

```
import sys
from pprint import pprint

pprint(sys.path)
```

And could you try to change `${workspaceRoot}` to `${workspaceFolder}` in the launch.json file?

**Update:**

```
"env": {"PYTHONPATH":"${workspaceRoot}"},
```

only works in debug mode, so you need to take `F5` to debug the python file instead of clicking the green triangle button on the top left.

Comment: dir structure you have shown is what I have. pprint is showing I have `c:\my_pkg\tests` in system path. But not `c:\my_pkg`. I think it needs `c:\my_pkg` in the system path to recognize the other folders. I have updated the launch.json to `${workspaceFolder}`. Still not working.

Comment: It works if I explicitly add `sys.path.append(r"C:\my_pkg")`. That is exactly I want to avoid

Comment: ok. issue is resolved. I needed to run it as test not as a python file. In command palette, I added it as unit tests. It then popped `Run Test | Debug Test` button over each test. It then works. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Dibyendu Dey, Could you check the update, thanks?